# Quitar sufijos .php y .html con nginx

Tags: php, html, nginx, dns

Hola buenos días tengo un problema al quitar los subfijos .php y .html antes tenía un .htuacces pero ahora lo tengo que hacer con una máquina diferente y necesita saber como quitar los .php y .html

Comment: nginx no maneja htaccess?? porque según se, nginx es similar a Apache. Ambos usan htaccess para tañes fines.

Comment: @Yenn nope, usa user.ini

Answer (score 0):

primero debes tener acceso al servicio de nginx y su configuracion, yo he jugado bastante usando docker y nginx-alpine.

En teoria seria de la siguiente forma usando las directivas `try_files` y `rewrite`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name tu_domino.com;

    root /ruta/a/tu/proyecto;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*).html$ /$1 permanent;
        rewrite ^/(.*).php$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # Cambia esto según tu versión de PHP
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Veamos ahora una Explicación de los puntos más importantes:

- `try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;`: Esta directiva intentará servir la URL tal como está (`$uri`), luego intentará servir la URL con una barra al final (`$uri/`) y si ninguna de esas coincide, pasará la solicitud a la ubicación `@rewrite`.
- `location @rewrite`: Aquí es donde realizamos las reescrituras de URL para eliminar los sufijos `.html` y `.php`.
- `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`: Esta es la ubicación donde se manejan los archivos PHP. Puedes personalizarla según tus necesidades, como cambiar la versión de PHP o la configuración del servidor PHP.

Después de hacer estos cambios, asegúrate de recargar la configuración de Nginx para que surtan efecto (dependera de tu S.O claro).

> sudo systemctl reload nginx